# App crush: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet weak
  var map: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak
  var mapCourse: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak
  var tableView: UITableView!

    struct User {

      var name: String
      var images: UIImage
      var coordinate: (Double, Double)
      var type: String
      var address: String
    }

  var rows = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    insertRowsMode3()
  }

  func insertRowsMode2() {

    for i in 0.. < users.count {
      insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: users[i])
    }

  }

  func insertRowMode2(ind: Int, usr: User) {

    let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

    rows = ind + 1
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
  }


  func insertRowsMode3() {

    rows = 0

    insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
  }

  func insertRowMode3(ind: Int) {
    let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
    rows = ind + 1
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

    guard ind < users.count - 1
    else {
      return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.15) {

      self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind + 1)
    }
  }

  func numberOfSections( in tableView: UITableView) - > Int {

    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {

    return rows
  }

  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
      for: indexPath) as!MyTableViewCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.MyImage.image = user.images
    cell.MyLabel.text = user.name
    cell.MyTypeLabel.text = user.type

    return (cell)
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast", sender: users[indexPath.row])

  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) - > CGFloat {
    return 100
  }

  override func prepare(
    for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any ? ) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

      guard
      let vc = segue.destination as ? FinalClass
      else {
        return
      }

      let guest = segue.destination as!FinalClass

      if let user = sender as ? User {

        guest.local = user.name

        guest.localImage = user.images

        guest.localType = user.type

        guest.localAddress = user.address
      }
    }
  }

  @IBAction func IndTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBack", sender: self)

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


}
```

Hello guys, this is the code of the ViewController where i get the error, i added a tableView with a particular animation but when i change the view and than come back with the  `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`the application crash because there is some inconsistency with rows data. As you can see, when i'm first visiting this `CourseClass2` controller i'm setting up row by calling `insertRowsMode3` in `viewDidAppear`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    insertRowsMode3()
}
```

The problem is when i come back the row data is not same as i have initialised it with zero and viewDidAppear doesn't get called.
I know the error but i don't how i can change my code to make it work. I really need an help.

The app crush exactly in this func

```
func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
         tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < users.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.15) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }
```

here   `tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)`

Comment: Pls make some review of code, that you've posted. Its like 200 lines. Leave just code, that we need to see. Thanks

Comment: Put breakpoint and check where this error encountered.

Comment: edit @RinkiNegi

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned invalid no of rows in section 0 :
In insertRowMode3 , you are inserting rows but not updating the table view.
So your table view getting the same count of no of rows in table view even afer updating, thats where inconsistency is.

Use tableview.beginUpdates() ,
then insert rows ,
increment ur rows value ,
then tableview.endUpdates()

Let me know if it doesn't help you out.

Comment: where i have to add view.beginUpdates() ? can you show me an example?

Comment: Before this : tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

Comment: u can refer this :               self.tableViewSlotsDay.beginUpdates()
            self.AddCountSection1 = self.AddCountSection1 + 1
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.AddCountSection1 - 1, section: 0)
            self.tableViewSlotsDay.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.tableViewSlotsDay.endUpdates()

Comment: ok understand, only 'AddcountSection' i do not know what i've to insert in this func to create it

Comment: no thats only row count(no of rows in tableview). I am maintaining this through this variable as per my needs. You are maintaining by using "rows variable" just replace these words.

Comment: let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.rows = self.rows + 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.rows - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

Comment: like this is ok ?

Comment: Why u used insert rows two times, you have to use it only once between begin updates and end updates methods.

Comment: right, sorry..this  rows = ind + 1
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.rows = self.rows + 1
        let indPath = IndexPath(item: ind - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: but now is crushing here 'self.tableView.endUpdates()' for this:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

Comment: Error is saying before updates you have 0 rows after 1 insertion there is 2 rows. Check properly what you are incrementing and where you are incrementing and what you are returning in no of rows in table view. Error is only this u are not returning proper no of rows count.