# UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have used two collection views which name is `cltnEdits` and `cltnTools`, i am Displaying `cltnTools` by default. when user click on any item of `cltnTools` then `cltnEdits` collection view is appeared otherwise it will be hidden. there is one cancel button with `cltnEdits`, whenever user click on that cancel button `cltnEdits` is disappeared(Hidden) and `cltnTools` is appeared.

**My both Collection views are in UIStackView**

I am getting following error while selecting element from collection view which name is `cltnTools`.

[image]

I have Tried following code to resolve this error but its not works for me

```
            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            cltnTools.reloadData()
            cltnTools.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnTools.layoutSubviews()
```

and also tried this

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

and added this `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate

```
func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

following is my **didSelect** method for **cltnTools**

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == cltnTools {

        selectedItem.push(item: "CltnTools")

        switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:

            //Edits

            arrImage = arrEditToolsImage
            arrText = arrEditToolsText

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            viewCrop.image = imgImage.image

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()

            break

        case 1:

            //Effect

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            arrImage = arrEffectToolsImage
            arrText = arrEffectToolsText

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()

            break

        case 2:

            //Colors

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            arrImage = arrColorToolsImage

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()

            break

        case 3:

            //Text

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            arrImage = arrTextToolsImage
            arrText = arrTextToolsText

            imgImage.addLabel()

            //Modify the Label
            imgImage.textColor = UIColor.black
            imgImage.textAlpha = 1
            imgImage.currentlyEditingLabel.closeView!.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Delete")
            imgImage.currentlyEditingLabel.rotateView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Resize")
            imgImage.currentlyEditingLabel.border?.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()


            break

        case 4:

            //Frame

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            print("Frame \(arrFrameToolsImage.count)")

            arrImage = arrFrameToolsImage

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()

            break

        case 5:

            //Goodies

            selectedItem.push(item: arrMainToolsText[indexPath.row])

            arrImage = arrGoodiesToolsImage

            print("Goodies \(arrGoodiesToolsImage.count)")

            cltnEdits.reloadData()
            cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            cltnEdits.layoutSubviews()

            toolsToEdits()

            break

        default:
            break

        }

    }
```

How can i resolve my error? someone please help!

**NOTE:** Before marking it duplicate please check my code that i have tried all solution given in other question asked on stack.

Comment: Check this out. I hope its quite relevent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199722/app-crush-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexc/44200197#44200197

Comment: What is your code in cltnTools 's didSelect method??

Comment: @Swift_Guru check my updated code.

Comment: the error is that there is no cell on given indexpath. So make sure your datasource is providing proper input for cell. And try one thing first invalidate layout and then reload collectionview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap `reloadData()` and `invalidateLayout()`, and additionally do not call `layoutSubviews` directly (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews))

```
cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
cltnEdits.reloadData()
cltnEdits.setNeedsLayout()
cltnEdits.layoutIfNeeded()


cltnTools.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
cltnTools.reloadData()
cltnTools.setNeedsLayout()
cltnTools.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Hi, we're currently looking into a similar issue. Can you explain why exactly `invalidateLayout()` should be called before `reloadData()` and not after? Is `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` necessary if you're already calling `invalidateLayout()`?